# SpriteBuilder blurs imported images

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, filtering, pixel, spritebuilder

I'm learning some animation using spritebuilder, but it is blurring (or antialiasing, I don't know) the images I'm importing and using.

To the left you can see the spritebuilder image, to the right the png in image viewer.

[image: left: spritebuilder, right: original]

Any idea of how to prevent this?

I changed _sprite.texture.antialiased to NO but the result is the same.
left texture.antialiased=NO, right texture.antialiased=YES (default)

[image: left: texture.antialiased=NO, right YES]

The code I used:

```
@implementation MainScene{
    CCSprite* _sprite1;
    CCSprite* _sprite2;
    }

-(void)didLoadFromCCB{        
    _karel1.texture.antialiased=NO;
    //NSLog(@"hi");
    self.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the texture filtering mode to nearest (point) filtering. In cocos2d this CCTexture property is incorrectly (or at least unusually) named [antialiased](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCTexture.html#//api/name/antialiased). It defaults to YES, so set it to NO to enable nearest/point filtering for the given texture.

For example:

```
thePlayerSprite.texture.antialiased = NO;
```

This can't be done in SpriteBuilder, you'll have to do this programmatically. [I created a feature request here](https://github.com/spritebuilder/SpriteBuilder/issues/719) because for pixel art this is a necessity.

Here's a more in-depth discussion from the SpriteBuilder forum explaining [how to enable pixel art filtering](http://forum.spritebuilder.com/t/solved-retro-style-graphics/1490/8).

Comment: hey thanks for replying! I test that but it doesn't works, I edited the question to add additional information

Comment: check that _karel1 is not nil

Comment: Maybe I should put that in the init method, and not in didLoadFromCCB

Comment: that won't make a difference since didLoadFromCCB runs shortly after init, but during init the texture would still be nil (if it gets called at all, CCSprite has a designated initializer that is not init).

Comment: didLoadFromCCB runs after all elements are loaded and displayed, right? It makes more sense turn off antialising before that. Remember that the texture wasn't nil

Comment: it runs after the node and its children have been loaded, but before the node is drawn

Comment: try running it in onEnter, perhaps some other node overrides the aliasing

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the 'scaling from' setting in SpriteBuilder, either per image or the default for the whole project to 1x. By default SpriteBuilder expects you to provide your images in 4x (iPad retina) resolution and scales it down depending on which device you are viewing the art on.

It looks like you are doing a pixel art game. This project shows an example of how you can set thing up: https://github.com/cocojoe/Pixel-Art-SpriteBuilder